# how to get combinations of items in an array field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
{_id:111,
keywords:['cs','ee','se']
},

{_id:112,
keywords:['cs','se','dd']
},
```

how can I get the relationship of keywords item?
like that:

```
{item1:'cs',item2:'ee',count:1},
{item1:'cs',item2:'se',count:2},
{item1:'ee',item2:'se',count:1},
{item1:'cs',item2:'dd',count:1},
{item1:'se',item2:'dd',count:1},
```

Comment: are you going to create a kind of `Cartesian product`? if there are only 2 documents that is not a problem, but larger data set could go over 16MB of document limit

Comment: i have **33** unique keywords and **3000+** documents

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64812637/get-all-possible-variations-from-mongodb-aggregation) is related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you relation from given example - this query should be a solution to your problem:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
            $unwind : "$keywords"
        }, {
            $lookup : {
                from : "collection",
                localField : "_id",
                foreignField : "_id",
                as : "items"
            }
        }, {
            $unwind : "$items"
        }, {
            $unwind : "$items.keywords"
        }, {
            $redact : {
                $cond : {
                    if  : {
                        $cmp : ["$keywords", "$items.keywords"]
                    },
                then : "$$DESCEND",
                else  : "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group : {
            _id : {
                k1 : "$keywords",
                k2 : "$items.keywords",
            },
            items : {
                $sum : 0.5
            }
        }
    }, {
        $sort : {
            "_id" : 1
        }
    }, {
        $project : {
            _id : 1,
            items : 1,
            a : {
                $cond : {
                    if  : {
                        $eq : [{
                                $cmp : ["$_id.k1", "$_id.k2"]
                            }, 1]
                    },
                then : "$_id.k2",
                else  : "$_id.k1"
            }
        },
        b : {
            $cond : {
                if  : {
                    $eq : [{
                            $cmp : ["$_id.k1", "$_id.k2"]
                        }, -1]
                },
            then : "$_id.k2",
            else  : "$_id.k1"
        }
    },

}
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            k1 : "$a",
            k2 : "$b",
        },
        items : {
            $sum : "$items"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        item1 : "$_id.k1",
        item2 : "$_id.k2",
        count : "$items"
    }
}
])
```

---

> output

```
{
    "item1" : "cs",
    "item2" : "dd",
    "count" : 1.0
}
{
    "item1" : "cs",
    "item2" : "ee",
    "count" : 1.0
}
{
    "item1" : "cs",
    "item2" : "se",
    "count" : 2.0
}
{
    "item1" : "dd",
    "item2" : "se",
    "count" : 1.0
}
{
    "item1" : "ee",
    "item2" : "se",
    "count" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: it worked.thx. and a good example for me.